# Solve Absolute Inequation by Using Triangle Inequality Theorem

Tags: absolute-value

Solve $|5-x|<6-|x|$ by using triangle inequality theorem.

I can solve this problem by using definition of absolute value and the solution is any numbers between $-\dfrac{1}{2}$ and $\dfrac{11}{2}$, but never solve it by using the triangle inequality theorem. Can you do that for me?

Comment: What is triangle inequality theorem?

Comment: The sum of the lengths of any two sides of a triangle is greater than the length of the third side.